# Angular Multi Select

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select, ng-options, angularjs-ng-options

Hello fair internet folk.

I'm trying to use ng-Options to create a multiple select element in Angular, and have it use a simple number array as its model.

```
$scope.model = [ 3 , 4 ];
```

At the moment, the furthest I've been able to get is if the model (showing the selected entries) matches the same format as ng-Options. For instance:

```
<select multiple
        data-ng-model="article"
        data-ng-options="category.name for category in categories track by category.id">
</select>

$scope.categories = [
    { id: 1, name: "ABC" },
    { id: 2, name: "DEF" },
    { id: 3, name: "GHI" },
    { id: 4, name: "JKL" }
];

$scope.article = [ 
    { id: 3 , name: "GHI" },
    { id: 4, name: "JKL" }
];
```

The above can be viewed as example 1 on the following : https://jsfiddle.net/hyvwpoL8/1/

Is it possible to treat categories.name as a descriptive label, and use only the value of categories.id as a means of binding it with the model (referenced as model above, or article2 on the fiddle)?

Thanks in advance for any tips !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `select as label` and do not use `track by`, both will not work together. You can see [running example](https://jsfiddle.net/hyvwpoL8/3/) or following code will work.

```
   <select multiple
    data-ng-model="article"
    data-ng-options="category.id as category.name for category in categories">
</select>

$scope.categories = [
    { id: 1, name: "ABC" },
    { id: 2, name: "DEF" },
    { id: 3, name: "GHI" },
    { id: 4, name: "JKL" }
];

$scope.article = [3,4];
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can treat name as descriptive label and use id as model value.
You can do like this

```
<select multiple 
data-ng-model="article2" 
data-ng-options="category.id as category.name for category in categories"></select>
$scope.categories = [
    { id: 1, name: "ABC" },
    { id: 2, name: "DEF" },
    { id: 3, name: "GHI" },
    { id: 4, name: "JKL" }
];
$scope.article2 = [ 3 , 4 ];
```

$scope.article2 containing ids will led to preselect options.
Above example is updated: https://jsfiddle.net/hyvwpoL8/2/

Angular Js empowers you with lots of options to choose from. Here are few:

```
label for value in array
select as label for value in array
label group by group for value in array
label disable when disable for value in array
```

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using native angular select - [ui-select](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select).